# Failed to linking bost_thread on solaris studio

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, solaris-10

I'm trying to compile and run the simple example of boost thread (see code below), but when I'm trying to run the program always I get "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)". I was compile dan run the program in other environments, on all these was succeeded (os x, linux), my problem only is in Solaris. I don't know what could be happening, someone could help me to figure out which is the problem?

## Command to compile it

```
-bash-3.00$ CC -m64 -L/export/home/ulcm/standalone/lib -lboost_thread -pthreads -DC7_Q -D_REENTRANT -I/export/home/ulcm/standalone/include -o main main.cpp
CC: Warning: Option -pthreads passed to ld, if ld is invoked, ignored otherwise
```

## When I trying to run

```
-bash-3.00$ ./main
Segmentation Fault (core dumped)
```

## boost version

```
1.48.0
```

## MDB output

```
-bash-3.00$ mdb ./main ./core
Loading modules: [ ld.so.1 libc.so.1 ]
> ::status
debugging core file of main (64-bit) from sgdev0
file: main
initial argv: ./main
threading model: multi-threaded
status: process terminated by SIGSEGV (Segmentation Fault)
>
> ::stack
libc.so.1`memcpy+0x1880()
libCstd.so.1`__1cDstdMbasic_string4Ccn0ALchar_traits4Cc__n0AJallocator4Cc___Hreserve6ML_v_+0x3a()
libstlport.so.1`__1cDstdG__copy4Cpkcn0AUback_insert_iterator4n0AMbasic_string4Ccn0ALchar_traits4C    c__n0A
Jallocator4Cc______Cl_6FTA3TBrkn0AbArandom_access_iterator_tag_pTC_4_+0x40e()
libstlport.so.1`__1cDstdO_Init_timeinfo6Frn0AK_Time_Info__v_+0x3c0()
libstlport.so.1`__1cDstdM_Locale_implTmake_classic_locale6F_p1_+0x472()
libstlport.so.1`__1cDstdGlocaleN_S_initialize6F_v_+0xe()
libstlport.so.1`__SLIP.INIT_A+0x10()
libstlport.so.1`_init+0x6d()
ld.so.1`call_init+0x10a()
ld.so.1`setup+0xa5e()
ld.so.1`_setup+0x2d0()
ld.so.1`_rt_boot+0x6d()
0xfffffd7fffdffd18()
>
```

## Solaris Version

```
-bash-3.00$ cat /etc/release
                       Solaris 10 10/08 s10x_u6wos_07b X86
           Copyright 2008 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
                        Use is subject to license terms.
                            Assembled 27 October 2008
```

## CC Version

```
-bash-3.00$ CC -V
CC: Sun C++ 5.11 SunOS_i386 2010/08/13
usage: CC [ options ] files.  Use 'CC -flags' for details
```

## Base code

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    #include <boost/thread.hpp>
    #include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>

    using namespace std;

    boost::mutex m;

    unsigned long long counter = 0;

    void funcMutex()
    {
        cout<<">> funcMutex()"<<endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            m.lock();
            ++counter;
            cout<<">> counter:"<<counter<<endl;
            m.unlock();
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        cout<<"Hello world!!!!"<<endl;
        // Start funcMutex on a thread.
        boost::thread t1(&funcMutex);
        boost::thread t2(&funcMutex);
        // Join threads.
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        cout<<"...end"<<endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: That version of Boost seems pretty old, can you upgrade? That said, can you make the mutex non-global, because from the backtrace it seems that the error happens during construction of globals (not the mutex, but maybe related). Further, does the same thing happen when only using one thread or no thread at all? What if you don't use a mutex anywhere?

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. It’s a pretty hard for me to change the boost version, because, on that environment also is running other apps that are using that version of boost (yes are old apps), anyway, I will try set up a fresh version of boost. About your other question, when I remove all references of mutex and threads of boost, and only keep the includes, I have the same errors (Segmentation fault (core dumped)). So do you have any other suggestion for me, something that I could try or check?

Comment: Thele's little other advise I can offer, I know very little about Solaris. However, I'd try to reduce the example further. Also, I'd check which compiler flags that are passed on the commandline are necessary and for what, maybe they change some binary interface in a way that the compiled code and some libraries don't interact any more.